# $|\exp(2\pi i mh)-1|<2^{1-\gamma}(2\pi)^{\gamma}|m|^{\gamma}h^{\gamma}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

im reading a book about fourieranalysis and found this inequality ...

> $|e^{2\pi imh}-1|\leq \min(2,2\pi|m|h)\leq 2^{1-\gamma}(2\pi)^{\gamma}|m|^{\gamma}h^{\gamma}$ with $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\gamma, h\in[0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$

Obviously the euler-relation gives us:

$$0\leq|e^{2\pi imh}-1|\leq|e^{2\pi imh}|+|-1|=2$$

The inequality $|e^{i\phi}-1|\leq|\phi|$ seems clear from geometry.

$$\Rightarrow |e^{2\pi imh}-1|\leq \min(2,2\pi|m|h)$$

> But what's about the last part?  $\min(2,2\pi|m||h|)\leq 2^{1-\gamma}(2\pi)^{\gamma}|m|^{\gamma}h^{\gamma}$ ?
>
> I can not see how to solve this inequality.

Thanks for your help, Tiling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already said, the inequality $|e^{i\phi}-1|\leq|\phi|$ is clear from geometry.
It can for example be derived as
$$
|e^{i\phi}-1|^2 = 2 - 2 \cos \phi = 2 - 2 \cos 2 \frac\phi 2
= 2 - 2 \cos^2 \frac\phi 2 + 2 \sin^2 \frac\phi 2 = 4 \sin^2 \frac\phi 2
\le 4 \big(\frac\phi 2 \bigr)^2   = \phi^2 \, .
$$

---

For $a, b > 0$ and $0 \le \gamma \le 1$ you have
$$
 a^{1 - \gamma} \ge \min(a, b) ^{1 - \gamma} \\
 b^\gamma \ge \min(a, b) ^\gamma
$$
because both $t\to t^{1 - \gamma}$ and $t \to t^\gamma$
are increasing functions. Therefore
$$
a^{1 - \gamma} b^\gamma \ge \min(a, b) ^{1 - \gamma} \min(a, b) ^\gamma
= \min(a, b) \, .
$$
With $a = 2$ and $b = 2\pi|m||h|$ you get the desired inequality
$$
\min(2,2\pi|m||h|)\leq 2^{1-\gamma}(2\pi)^{\gamma}|m|^{\gamma}h^{\gamma}
$$

Comment: You also get $(1-c)a+cb \ge (1-c)\min(a,b)+c \min(a, b) = \min(a, b)$, so you have a similar inequality with multiplication instead of exponentiation. Somehow, I feel that the phrase that applies is "Less in these than meets the eye."

Comment: Thanks Martin R, for your answer. But how does the inequality $a^{1-\gamma}b^{\gamma}\geq \min(a,b)^{1-\gamma}\cdot\min(a,b)^{\gamma}$ works?

Comment: @Tiling: I have expand the answer, hope that helps!

Comment: @MartinR Thanks alot!